# How to hide exact url call of $routeProvider from user

Tags: angularjs

Well, I've implemented angularJS and I am calling different views which is being handled by `$routeProvider` . The problem is that for eg:

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/prodDetails/:prodID', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/productDetails.html',
    controller: 'ProductController'
  }).
```

Now, if I click on:

```
<a ng-href="#prodDetails/{{ prod.id }}">View Product</a>
```

The browser url will show `prod.id` in the url tab. How can I manipulate url to hide sensitive info in it.

Comment: Erm you can't - a url is a url - you can't hide the ID then expect the page to navigate correctly unless you hash everything, which I wouldn't do - why is the product ID secret anyway?

Comment: The `id` resides in the HTML anyway. Also, if you refresh the page and the ID is gone, what will you do?

Comment: what would you rather see in url?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: Well, it was suggested to me that we shouldn't show exact product or other details to user.I've seen websites  using urls which are hard to read and are kinda encrypted. With some hexa ids or with random alphabets

Comment: That's not a good philosophy to me - what if a user calls/emails about a product and they haven't got a product ID to reference? eg the product description is glass table of which you sell 200 different types?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Angular UI Router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/). it will solve your problem without doing anything. you can then pass parameter using params object given by angular-ui-router.

Comment: Well, i guess this will hide the id from browser ur. I would like mostly to encrypr in some kinda way

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular ui router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router)

You can achieve that by doing:

```
$stateProvider.
  state('productDetail', {
    url: '/prodDetails',
    templateUrl: 'templates/productDetails.html',
    controller: 'ProductController',
    params: {
      productId: 'defaultId'
    }
  })
```

And in the html:

```
<a ui-sref="productDetail({productId: prod.id})">View Product</a>
```

You can have access to the productId from the controller with the service $stateParams.

**EDIT**:

Let's say you have a `encodeId` and a `decodeId` functions:

```
<a ui-sref="productDetail({productId: encodeId(prod.id)})">View Product</a>
```

and in the controller:

```
app.controller(function($stateParams) {
  var id = decodeId($stateParams.productId);
});
```

Comment: Well, i guess this will hide the id from browser ur. I would like mostly to encrypr in some kinda way

Comment: What would you encrypt? It doesn't make sense to encrypt something that is already in your browser...

Comment: Just so that the user cant find any patternin urls. They should look random.